# Strongly Typed Tree Hierarchy Using Protocols and Associated Types

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to design a strongly typed hierarchy of objects using protocols, but can't quite get it right.

For illustration, suppose that the concrete types that will end up adopting these protocols are the *classes* `Country`, `State`, and `City`.

Each node can have a parent (except the root object) and/or children (except the leaf objects): All `State` instances are children of the single `Country` instance and have it as parent, and they have `City` instances as children, etc.

So I start with these two protocols:

```
/// To be adopted by State and City
///
protocol Child: AnyObject {
    associatedtype ParentType: AnyObject 
    // (-> so that property `parent` can be weak)

    weak var parent: ParentType? { get }
} 

/// To be adopted by Country and State
///
protocol Parent: AnyObject {
    associatedtype ChildType: AnyObject
    // (-> for symmetry)

    var children: [ChildType] { get }
}
```

I have **two** separate protocols instead of one that groups all the above requirements, because I don't want to have to specify a "dummy" `typealias ParentType` for the root class `Country` (which is meaningless), nor a "dummy" `typealias ChildType` for the leaf class `City`.

**Instead**, I can separate the parent and child behaviours and just have the intermediate class `State` adopt *both* protocols.

---

**Next**, I want to make my clases initializable from a dictionary read from disk. For the child classes, I want to specify the parent at the moment of instantiation, so I came up with this scheme:

```
protocol UnarchivableChild: Child {
    init(dictionary: [String: Any], parent: ParentType?)
}

protocol UnarchivingParent: Parent {
    associatedtype ChildType: UnarchivableChild

    func readChildren(fromDictionaries dictionaries: [[String: Any]]) -> [ChildType]
}
```

As it stands, it looks like I could go one step further and add a default implementation of the method `readChildren(fromDictionaries:)`, like this:

```
extension UnarchivingParent {
    func readChildren(fromDictionaries dictionaries: [[String: Any]]) -> [ChildType] {
        return dictionaries.flatMap({ dictionary in
            return ChildType(dictionary: dictionary, parent: self)
        })
    }
}
```

...because in this protocol, `ChildType` is constrained to `UnarchivableChild`, so it should support the initializer...? But I get:

> Cannot invoke 'ChildType' with an argument list of type '(dictionary: ([String : Any]), parent: Self)'

*(why the capitalized "Self"?)*

I think I am missing something about how associated types work...

**How can I code this default implementation?**

---

**Update:** Apparently, passing self is the problem somehow. I modified the code to:

```
protocol Node: AnyObject {
}

protocol Parent: Node {
    associatedtype ChildNodeType: Node
    var children: [ChildNodeType] { get set }
}

protocol Child: Node {
    associatedtype ParentNodeType: Node
    weak var parent: ParentNodeType? { get set }
}

protocol UnarchivableChild: Child {
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) // Removed parent parameter!
}

protocol UnarchivingParent: Parent {
    associatedtype ChildNodeType: UnarchivableChild
    func readChildren(fromDictionaries dictionaries: [[String: Any]]) -> [ChildNodeType]
}

extension UnarchivingParent {
    func readChildren(fromDictionaries dictionaries: [[String: Any]]) -> [ChildNodeType] {
        return dictionaries.flatMap({
            let child = ChildNodeType(dictionary: $0)
            // Assign parent here instead:
            child.parent = self // < ERROR HERE

            return child
        })
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Self' to type '_?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading over [The Swift Programmng Language: Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179) (Section: "Extensions With a Generci Where Clause"), I found the appropriate syntax to achieve what I wanted. I settled for this code (type names are slighlty different form the ones in the original question):

```
protocol DictionaryInitializable {
    init(dictionary: [String: Any])
}

protocol ChildNode: AnyObject {
    associatedtype ParentType: AnyObject

    weak var parent: ParentType? { get set }
}

protocol ParentNode {
    associatedtype ChildType: AnyObject

    var children: [ChildType] { get set }
}

// This 'WHERE' clause fixes the issue:
extension ParentNode where ChildType: DictionaryInitializable,
ChildType: ChildNode, ChildType.ParentType == Self {

    func readChildren(from dictionaries: [[String: Any]]) -> [ChildType] {
        return dictionaries.map({
            return ChildType(dictionary: $0)
        })
    }
}
```

The first constraint of the where clause lets me call the initializer `init(dictionary:)`, the second one guarantees the presence of the property `parent`, and the third one lets me assign `self` as its value.

Alternatively, I can change:

```
protocol ParentNode {
    associatedtype ChildType: AnyObject
```

to:

```
protocol ParentNode {
    associatedtype ChildType: ChildNode
```

...and skip the second constraint.